# How to access absolute path to Gruntfile within Gruntfile?

Tags: compass-sass, gruntjs

My `Gruntfile.js` contains a task for Compass:

```
grunt.initConfig({

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  // FILE PATHS (custom)
  dir: {
    css:          'resources/styles/css',
    fonts:        'resources/fonts',
    html:         'resources/html',
    images:       'resources/images',
    includes:     'resources/includes',
    node_modules: 'node_modules',
    prototypes:   'resources/html/prototypes',
    resources:    'resources',
    scripts:      'resources/scripts',
    scss:         'resources/styles/scss',
    styles:       'resources/styles',
    styleguide:   'resources/styleguide',
    vendor:       'resources/vendor',
    user: {
       htdocs: '/Volumes/VR\ Mini\ Backup/Backups/Web/Active/myproject/htdocs'
    }
  },

  // COMPASS
  compass: {
    dist: {
      options: {
        ...
        importPath: [
          '<%= dir.user.htdocs %>/<%= dir.resources %>/vendor',
          '<%= dir.user.htdocs %>/<%= dir.resources %>/fonts'
        ]
```

One of the Compass [options](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) is `importPath`. This expects an absolute/system path. An example `importPath` is `/system/path/to/htdocs/resources/vendor`.

As several developers will be working on my project, I'd like to make `/system/path/to/htdocs` dynamic.

Is there any way to access the path to `Gruntfile.js` from within this file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can leverage [Node's path module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

At the top of your gruntfile, add `var path = require('path');`.

`path.resolve()` will give you the absolute path.